# Retrieve value from array in cakePHP

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I want to know how to retrieve the values from array that is looking like that:

```
    Array ( [0] => Array 
( [Group] => Array 
( [id] => 1 
[name] => admin 
[created] => 2013-04-15 14:13:19
[modified] => 2013-04-15 14:13:19 
)
 [Admin] => Array 
( [0] => Array 
(
 [id] => 1
 [email] => iman@yahoo.com 
[username] => iman 
[password] => 9e217e2039912c40b0f179f801e2d3e9fe8eb32e 
[active] => 1 
[mobile] => 01000000000 
[created] => 2013-04-15 13:56:02
 [modified] => 2013-04-15 14:44:59 
[group_id] => 1 
[tokenhash] => e2e1bbffc40d3f909594a268f0f3ec127fabe5c00e01c5f0644a1950aa37e6103ad18542a8731a2ad9ade283916281977677523098cd25a296116d078fbbc231
 [image] => d 
)...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried already?

As far as I can see based on the limited information provided, you have two options; access a value directly by providing the relevant keys or looping over the array.

Say you want to access the `name` of the first `Group` in the array, which I presume is stored in a variable (called `$yourArray` in this example):

```
   $yourArray[0]['Group']['name']
```

The result will be 'admin'.

Looping would give you the benefit of retrieving all the group names (or any other value):

```
  foreach ($yourArray as $value) {
    //Output the Group name
    echo $value['Group']['name'];

    //Output the Admin email
    echo $value['Admin'][0]['email'];
  }
```

But the above is all fairly standard PHP stuff and not specific to CakePHP. It might be good to read up on the basics of PHP as well, as CakePHP adds another layer of abstraction by providing all kinds of framework conventions and convenience methods.